# touchMoveStopPropagation property doesn't work in swiperjs since 9.0.0 version

Tags: swiper.js

In previous version 8.4.7 touchMoveStopPropagation worked good. But since 9.0.0 touchmove event pops up when swiping even with property touchMoveStopPropagation = true. It can be easily reproduced if you set the listener to the parent wrapper.
The problem remains relevant even if you upgrade the version to the latest 11.0.6
Do you now how to fix it?

```
`<div onTouchMove={(e)=>{console.log(e)}}>
   <Swiper
                    ...
                    touchMoveStopPropagation={true}
                    
                >
</div>`
```

I tried to pass onSliderMove={handleSliderMove} to Swiper component with event?.stopPropagation()
but without succeed